# How to fetch innerHTML using getElementsByTagName in PHP

Tags: php

Below is my PHP code. I am able to get `innerHTML` using `$node = $doc->getElementById( 'first' );` but I am not getting `innerHTML` when I am using `$doc->getElementsByTagName('td');`

Inside `<td>` this is my code: `$html2 = '<td width="112"><p><span lang="EN-US">Question </span></p></td>';`

```
<?php    
       //$html = '<div id="first"><h1>Hello</h1></div><div id="second"><p>World!</p></div>';
       $html2 = '<td width="112"><p><span lang="EN-US">Question </span></p></td>';

    $doc  = new \DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML( $html2 );
    //$node = $doc->getElementById( 'first' );
    $node = $doc->getElementsByTagName('td');

    if( $node instanceof \DOMNode ) {
        echo innerHTML( $node, true );
        //Output: <div id="first"><h1>Hello</h1></div>    

        echo innerHTML( $node, false );
        // Output: <h1>Hello</h1>
    }

    function innerHTML( \DOMNode $node, $include_target_tag = true ) {
      $doc = new \DOMDocument();
      $doc->appendChild( $doc->importNode( $node, true ) );
      $html = trim( $doc->saveHTML() );
      if ( $include_target_tag  ) {
          return $html;
      }
      return preg_replace( '@^<' . $node->nodeName . '[^>]*>|</' . $node->nodeName . '>$@', '', $html );
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`getElementById` will return a single node of type `DOMNode`. However `getElementsByTagName` will always return an array of `DOMNodes` which is not an instance of `DOMNode`, so your `if` condition will fail.

You could try to get the first element of the result and that will be of type `DOMNode`.